# Join column header with array n times

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets-formula, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I am looking to join column headers with their respective arrays any number of times depending on if the cell is not empty and if it has a checkbox.

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14OnldnEvfVdr7vhATrKUzzQE3AK22yjketGy4Z-HEoM/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

I have a formula close but I can't get it to repeat for the array with the respective values.

```
=JOIN(", ",ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$2:$3),"SELECT Col2 WHERE Col1 = FALSE AND Col2 IS NOT NULL")&"-"))&" : "&JOIN(", ",ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$2:$3),"SELECT Col2 WHERE Col1 = TRUE AND Col2 IS NOT NULL")&"-"))
```

This needs to be dynamic, meaning that if I add a new column header and values in column D it includes that set. Along with an infinite number of rows, however the rows sizes will always match. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(REGEXREPLACE({
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A3:C3&"-"&A4:C8, A2:C2=FALSE)&","),,9^9)), 
 IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A4:C8))/0, ":"), 
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A3:C3&"-"&A4:C8, A2:C2=TRUE)&","),,9^9))}, 
 ",$", )),,9^9)))
```

[image]